# i have problem when i try to install app on my phone

Tags: whatsapp

I am having a problem when I try to install an app on my windows phone.when i try to install app on my windows phone it say my family account is need, but I am not a child and my Microsoft account is completed.what should I do now with this phone?
And there is no one who use Windows phone in my family